# WPF Combobox selectedindex binding

Tags: wpf, combobox, binding, selectedindex

I have difficulties binding the selectedindex of a combobox to an object.
This is my code:

---

1. (Part of) CustomerClass

   ```
   public class Customer : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
   public int CountryCode
   {
       get { return _CountryCode; }
       set { _CountryCode = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
   }
   }
   ```

2a. (Part of) CustomListItem

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="cboCountryCode" Grid.Column="5" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="LongName" SelectedIndex="{Binding CountryCode, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

2b. (Part of) CustomListItem

```
public partial class CustomerListItem : UserControl
        {
            public CustomerListItem()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                ObservableCollection<CountryCode> Liste = CountryCodes.Instance.List;
                cboCountryCode.DataContext = Liste;
            }
```

3. (Part of) MainPage

   ```
   <ItemsControl Name="itcCustomers" Style="{StaticResource ItemsControlVirtualizedStyle}">
       <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <local:CustomerListItem/>
           </DataTemplate>
       </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   </ItemsControl>
   ```

The Combobox List Items are shown correctly.
But the selected index is not working at all
[See this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9fjz.png)

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I tried to bind the Combobox to two different Datasources. One for the collection and one for the selectedindex. Now I combinde these two Datasources into one class and bound to it, now it works fine